# how to convert text value to minute and second

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static int count = 120;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        label1.Visible = true;
        label1.Text = count.ToString();

    }
    protected void tmer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = (--count).ToString();

        int m = 0;

        if (Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text) <= m)
        {
            count = 120;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }

}
```

this is my code for countdown and its work perfectly..

but it shows 120 , 119 instead of this integer value i want to convert that into like

```
 2:00 , 1:59 , 1:58 etc..
```

so how can i do that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The `count` variable is static, so all requests use the same value.

Comment: Try using a TimeSpan instead of an int to record remaining time

Comment: @TimSchmelter I assume it's static so that it survives the page refresh... Jay - you do know that you'll get the same time for each user on the site right?

Comment: nah...it is not get the same time for all...

Comment: how can i saw that into mm:ss

Comment: Bad idea, to make a call to the server each second...., even the redirect can be done with javascript, and the countdown can be done in javascript. And the static, will be the same for all users, so this is not work as expected

Comment: but hoe can i do that with javascript?

Comment: Search on google for "countdown javascript example"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(--count).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

Maybe that could help you out

Further Information you will find under the following link:

[TimeSpan.FromSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.fromseconds(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Solution**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static int count = 120;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        label1.Visible = true;
        label1.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(count).ToString(@"mm\:ss");

    }
    protected void tmer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var c = --count;
        label1.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(c).ToString(@"mm\:ss");

        int m = 0;

        if (c <= m)
        {
            count = 120;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just store the whole thing as a TimeSpan?

Answer (score -1):

```
            string strrr = "159";
            TimeSpan t=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(strrr));
            Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
```

Comment: Add some explanation please, don't write code only answers!

Comment: And do not mix, console with web applications.

Comment: @Aristos : why does methods behavior changes in web application

Comment: @vinayak The `console` is not exist on web. What else to say. Either you give good working snippet code, either not. The code on question have all ready in integer the number. You change it to string, and convert it again - so you probably copy/paste some random code. This is not a good answer question.